# Redis LIST keys gets corrupted

Tags: redis

I have stumbled upon a very bogus issue with a Redis List that is breaking our Queueing system.

This behavior has only been observed on our Redis SaaS provider, we could not replicate on local Redis servers, both running on version 2.8.12.

The issue arrises with the creation of a LIST type key. The key is named `nsworker:queue:latency-check`. This key is accessed with the following commands:

- `blpop`: To pop the first item in the list, with blocking wait until an item is available.
- `rpush`: To push items to the list.

The issue is that after the first few operations on that specific key item it then gets "borked" in lack of any better term. The specific key is like sucking all commands like a black hole with no effect...

I have closed all services and servers and logged in the redis db using redis-cli from my local, observe the set following of commands:

```
> exists nsworker:queue:latency-check
(integer) 0
```

Apparently the list does not exist, let's try LLEN:

```
> llen nsworker:queue:latency-check
(integer) 0
```

0 length, let's now try a RPUSH and LLEN afterwards:

```
> rpush nsworker:queue:latency-check 1
(integer) 1
> llen nsworker:queue:latency-check
(integer) 0
```

Redis confirms an item was pushed but the Length on the list still reports 0! Trying LPOP:

```
> lpop nsworker:queue:latency-check
(nil)
```

Using LPUSHX to only push if list exists we get a 0 response:

```
> lpushx nsworker:queue:latency-check 1
(integer) 0
```

LPUSH without X has the same effect as RPUSH:

```
> lpush nsworker:queue:latency-check 1
(integer) 1
> llen nsworker:queue:latency-check
(integer) 0
> exists nsworker:queue:latency-check
(integer) 0
```

Bottom line, for some unknown to us reason, the queue keys gets corrupt.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Have you contacted your Redis SaaS provider with the issue?

Comment: OK, I can see that you have done so :)

Comment: Ha! How did you see that? (yes i have)

Comment: I know a guy who knows a guy who knows a guy at your provider :) The behavior that you're describing isn't normal and I can't say I've heard about a similar case. Our team is looking into the matter so I want to hear their opinion on it - shouldn't take long

Comment: Further investigation revealed that all BLPOP client connections where remaining open even after the application exited, using `CLIENT LIST` I was able to view clients that were created days before. This doesn't mean we found the root of the problem, just what is causing it...

Comment: Yep, a first step but definitely not over - I appreciate your patience and being so accommodating with us.